# Реализация прямой трансляции на сайте через веб-камеру

Tags: javascript

Вкратце расскажу историю возникновения идеи.Хотим прикрепить камеру к дрону,запустить дрон,и вместе с этим передавать **прямую трансляцию** с камеры на собственный сайт.
У меня есть идея. Хочу для того использовать библиотеку webcam.js.Но как мне известно,данная библиотека подключает веб-камеру ноута.

Вопрос:Можно ли,используя данную библиотеку,подключиться к удаленной веб-камере???

Для ознакомления с библиотекой прикрепляю [ссылку](https://makitweb.com/how-to-capture-picture-from-webcam-with-webcam-js/).

Есть еще идея получения HTML-кода камеры для реализации этого,но js удобнее.

Comment: Нужно ознакамливаться не с рандомными библиотеками, а с протоколом, по которому передаётся видеопоток с камеры дрона

Comment: @andreymal Согласен.Но что же делать потом? чуть подробнее можно?  И если не трудно,на мой вопрос ответьте,Да или нет например.